# "ImportError: No module named selenium" on VSCode

Tags: python, selenium

I'm making a project with selenium, and the following error is disturbing me. I'm using VSCode with Code Runner, and my OS is Ubuntu 20.04:

```
[Running] python -u "/home/albomonco/Desktop/forca.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/albomonco/Desktop/forca.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.028 seconds
```

I have installed Firefox geckodriver on github, and I have put geckodriver to my PATH in /usr/bin and in /usr/local/bin using "sudo cp /geckodriver/path /usr/bin". I have already done "pip3 install selenium".

What is really weird is that if I go to Terminal, and run "python3 name_of_file.py", it works. I have searched a lot, and I didn't found anything about it. I also tested on IDLE IDE, and it worked fine.

Comment: Do you use conda env?

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer of [Raj Dhaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10464368/raj-dhakad)

Uninstall Selenium using `pip uninstall selenium`
Then create a New Folder on your preferred location, (Like Desktop, or D drive, etc.)
Open that folder in Visual Studio Code.
Now go to the Terminal of VS Code and create a Virtual Environment (Google python Virtual Environment if you don't know how to create one)
Then, install selenium in that virtual Environment using `pip install selenium`
You will see some files are included in your folder after `pip install selenium` (`pipfile` and `pipfile.lok`)
Lastly, install pyLint to your virtual environment using `pipenv install pylint --dev`